# Power Electronics control for greater than 100V input?

Tags: power, power-electronics, control

An example application is 270VDC input to 150VDC output synchronous buck.  Is there anything wrong with using an off the shelf controller such as LT8210 and implementing isolation amplifiers and external gate drivers?

Will the bandwidth of the isolation amplifiers affect the control loop significantly?

If anyone has resources to learn more about this I would appreciate it. I think typically it would be done with a custom microcontroller solution but I am wondering if that is necessary.

Comment: Please post a schematic with said isolation amplifiers. What switching frequency and output current are we talking about?

Comment: A buck converter is common-ground; why would isolation be required? Please provide more information about your background application, or what is generally motivating your question.